# How to pass Laravel Resource API data to Vuejs?

Tags: laravel, api, axios, vue-resource, vuetify.js

If I `return Record::all();` using Axios into Vuetify datatable, the data will show. But if I use return `RecordResource::collection(Record::all());` the data won't even be stored in a local variable.

I checked the data in the networks tab and the data is there, but in the Vue tab there's no data in the datatable. No errors either.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Record;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\RecordResource;
use App\Http\Resources\RecordCollection;

class RecordController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return RecordResource::collection(Record::all());
    }
}
```

Here's my Vuejs script:

```
 <script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        search: '',
        totalItems: 0,
        items: [],
        loading: true,
        pagination: {},
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Teacher Name',
            align: 'left',
            value: 'user'
          },
          { text: 'Type', align: 'center', value: 'type' },
          { text: 'Time', align: 'center', value: 'time' }
        ]
      }
    },
    watch: {
      pagination: {
        handler () {
          this.getDataFromApi()
            .then(data => {
              this.items = data.items
              this.totalItems = data.total
              console.log(this.items)
            })
        },
        deep: true
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getDataFromApi()
        .then(data => {
          this.items = data.items
          this.totalItems = data.total
        })
    },
    methods: {
      getDataFromApi () {
        this.loading = true
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
          let items = []
          this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/records')
          .then(response => {
            items = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });

          const total = items.length


          if (this.pagination.sortBy) {
            items = items.sort((a, b) => {
              const sortA = a[sortBy]
              const sortB = b[sortBy]

              if (descending) {
                if (sortA < sortB) return 1
                if (sortA > sortB) return -1
                return 0
              } else {
                if (sortA < sortB) return -1
                if (sortA > sortB) return 1
                return 0
              }
            })
          }

          if (rowsPerPage > 0) {
            items = items.slice((page - 1) * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage)
          }

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading = false
            resolve({
              items,
              total
            })
          }, 1000)
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My Record Resource looks like this

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'user' => User::find($this->user_id)->fname . " " . User::find($this->user_id)->mname . " " . User::find($this->user_id)->lname,
            'type' => $this->created_at->hour < 12 ? 'Morning ' . $this->type : 'Afternoon ' . $this->type,
            'time' => $this->created_at->toDayDateTimeString()
        ];
    }
}
```

Example data from the API resource

```
// 20180227062317
// http://localhost:8000/api/records

[
  {
    "user": "Chadd Q. Rau",
    "type": "Afternoon In",
    "time": "Sun, Jan 28, 2018 8:22 PM"
  },
  {
    "user": "Rosalind J. Sanford",
    "type": "Morning In",
    "time": "Tue, Jan 23, 2018 12:15 AM"
  },
  {
    "user": "Rosalind J. Sanford",
    "type": "Morning In",
    "time": "Mon, Feb 12, 2018 12:45 AM"
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you try to compare the json when you return `all()` and when you return `collection` ? Maybe the data aren't formated as expected.

Comment: they return the same format but with different results due to the API resource

Comment: Datatable will only work with attended results. Maybe you have a problem with the format or the content. A sample could help to see where the problem is. Some libraries will add a "data" key on the json's root which will result a `response.data.data` on axios as @Bitfumes says.

Comment: i edited my post. @cbaconnier. I also remove the data wrapping from the resource so that the response will only have 1 data wrapping

Comment: I will ask you in a different way: Can you confirm me, that between the method `all()` and the method `collection()`, the json on the network tab are exactly the same?

Comment: How can you confirm the two? Sry im still new to apis and vue

Comment: When you call `http://localhost:8000/api/records`, can you confirm me that when either way you return `all()` or `collection(Record::all())` the [preview/response](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#preview) of your request is the same or not ? If not, what is the difference ?

Comment: The only difference is the data wrapping

Comment: So, yes that what I thought, and as we told you : `Some libraries will add a "data" key on the json's root which will result a response.data.data on axios as @Bitfumes says.` that mean change your `response.data` to `response.data.data`

Comment: Already did that but nothing happens

Comment: I can only see two possibilities:   `RecordResource` doesn't include the header 'Content-Type: application/json' _and I'm not even sure it's required_. OR you have messed up somewhere because there's not possible way that `response.data` **without the data wrapping** works and `response.data.data` doesn't work **with the "data wrapping"** if in both cases the content are exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, thats what im trying to figure out. The content is the same on both returns. I also think theres something missing like headers or something. And im new to resource api so i dont know why it doesnt work.haha

Answer (score 3):

Why creating item variable, instead define a data field in the vie data()

```
data(){
  return {
    item : {}
  }
}
```

Now in your axios

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/records')
      .then(response => {
        this.items = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

If you are using resource::collection then may be you have to say response.data.data in your .then part